# Firebase: FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ ... incorrect data check

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I was working on a Firebase project locally, and it was working fine in emulators. However, after upgrading Firebase-tools to version 12.4.3, I encountered the following error while deploying:

> Error: FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch [https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[project-name]/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com](https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%5Bproject-name%5D/services/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com): incorrect data check

To investigate if I was doing something wrong, I started a new project from scratch, but I'm facing the same error during the `firebase init` command.

Here are the details of my setup:

```
MacOS v10.13.6
Node.js v16.20.1 (I cannot upgrade to Node 18 due to my MacOS version)
NPM v8.19.4 (the version that comes with Node 16.20.1)
TSC 5.1.6
Firebase-tools 12.4.3
```

So far, I have attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

```
Upgraded to Node 18, but it crashed because it requires MacOS 10.15
Downgraded to Node 16.20.1
Completely removed NPM
Cleared NPM cache with: sudo npm cache clear --force
Reinstalled NPM 8.19.4
Reinstalled Firebase and firebase-tools 12.4.3
```

At this point, I'm unsure about the next steps to take. Can you please suggest any further troubleshooting or solutions for this issue?

Thasnks!

Answer (score 0):

Well cheching the JSON from https://registry.npmjs.org I determined that the Firebase versions that works in my `MacOS v10.13.6` are:

```
Firebase: 10.0.0
Firebase tools: 11.30.0
```

Using:

```
Node: 16.20.1
NPM: 8.19.4
```

https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase
https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools

So I removed completely Node and NPM and reinstall `Node 16.20.1` and install firebase using:

```
sudo npm install -g firebae@10.0.0
sudo npm install -g firebae-tools@11.30.0
```

That works for me.